# What's the difference between `/[a-z]??/g` and `/[a-z]?/g`? Will they match a position?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

How the following code differ and how they work?

I am learning regular expressions in javascript. I am confused about the following code. I want to know how they work, and their differences.

```
"abc".replace(/[a-z]??/g, "-")  
// "-a-b-c-"
"abc".match(/[a-z]??/g)
// ["", "", "", ""]

"abc".replace(/[a-z]?/g, "-")
// "----"
"abc".match(/[a-z]?/g);
// ["a", "b", "c", ""]
```

Why there are four matches for both of them? How come the first replace method insert the `-` at both beginning and end?
Why the second only match the end not the beginning of the "abc"?

Answer (score 0):

The quantifier '?' by itself just means "match zero or one of the preceding character/character group." However, adding a second '?' makes the preceding quantifier lazy, matching as few characters as possible. This means that the `.match()` function attempts to match exactly zero of the preceding character group, which can cause rather funky behavior. In this case, it's detecting an empty string before and after each character, a behavior that isn't immediately apparent, so `.replace()` will stick the `"-"` character in those empty string slots — that is, between each character.

However, without the second `?`, we have just the vanilla `?` quantifier, matching zero or one of the preceding character/character group. Given character group `[a-z]`, your regex matches each alphabetical character by itself, as expected — and also has a single empty match somewhere, hence the replacement `"----"` (as opposed to the more intuitive `"---"`).

Comment: Why the empty match for the vanilla `?` quantifier? I am confused.